# press Javascript generated button with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape the contents of the table in this site: [breachlevelindex](http://www.breachlevelindex.com/index.html?utm_source=bli-pr-20140217&utm_medium=press-release&utm_campaign=breach-level-index#!breach-database). So far I succesfully get the contents of the first 20 rows on the table using the following:

```
    url = 'http://www.breachlevelindex.com/index.html?utm_source=bli-pr-20140217&utm_medium=press-release&utm_campaign=breach-level-index#!breach-database'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
    driver.set_window_size(100000, 200000)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5) # wait to load
```

at this point I can scrape the table content, but how to programatically press the `next` button and reload the contents of page ?

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You locate the next button using CSS and then click it, like so :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sprite.next-page.clickable").click()
```

or using javascript like so :

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.sprite.next-page.clickable').click()")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.next-page").click()
```